# Converting a string date to a Date field using scripted fields in kibana

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack

Hi I am working on ELK stack. I have a date in the form of a `string` like below:

`"23/Nov/2017:02:35:02 +0000"`

Now I want to use scripted fields in `kibana` to convert the string date time to a `date` field.

Anyone can help me with what to put in the script? or How can I go about it?

Comment: Why use scripted field for this, you can use logstah date filter ( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html ) to convert the date time string to Date

Comment: @Ram can you share a sample for this filter? It'll be of great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for your case lets say the date is in the field `{ logdate:"23/Nov/2017:02:35:02 +0000" }`

In order to convert the logdate(string) to a timestamp value, we can use a [Logstash Date filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html)

In our case, the date filter should look something like below, this filter will parse the date time and save it to the @timestamp filed which is default if you want to save it to a particular field used the [target](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-target) setting

```
filter {
  date {
    match => [ "logdate", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}
```

Let me know if the filter works for you